# structure alignment compiled ok in c,failed in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I have the following souce about structure which compiled ok in gcc 4.4.6 :

```
struct st1
{
    char name[12];
    int heartbeat ;
    double price ;
    int iFlag ;
} ;

struct st2  {
    struct st1 ;
    char pad[64 - sizeof(struct st1)] ;
} __attribute__((aligned(64))) ;

int main (void)
{
    printf("length of struct st2=(%d)\n",sizeof(struct st2) ) ;
}


gcc -fms-extensions test1.c -o test1.exe

./test1.exe ===> length of struct st2=(64)
```

I copy test1.c  to test1.cpp  and try to compile as :

```
g++ -fms-extensions test1.cpp -o test1.exe
```

and then I got :

test1.cpp:23: error: invalid application of sizeof to incomplete type st2::st1

I know this error showes   char pad[64 - sizeof(struct st1)] ; does not work in g++ ,
although it works in gcc  ,  if I like this works in g++ , what can  I do ?

Comment: Not sure why it got downvoted, seems like a perfectly reasonable question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your struct st2:

```
struct st1 ;
```

This is a forward declaration of a `struct st1`.
Here, you are basically saying to your compiler : "Hey, there's a `struct st1` in the namespace of the `struct st2` (hence the `st2::st1`), but I'm not going to give you its properties !"
Since you are not providing its properties, the compiler will raise an "incomplete type" error : it can't know about the size of this type, and therefore cannot resolve your `sizeof`.

If you want to have an instance of your `struct st1` in your `struct st2`, you should write:

```
struct st1 my_variable_name;
```

This will effectively add an instance of your `struct st1` in your `struct st2`.

If you DON'T want an instance of your `struct st1` in your `struct st2`, just remove this line - your compiler already knows about the `struct st1`, since it's declared right above.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "struct" and just use sizeof(st1). By adding "struct", you're telling the compiler to define a new struct st1 in the scope of st2. Hence why it says "st2::st1".